# IONIC FRAMEWORK Build Xcode Error :(

Tags: xcode, build, ionic-framework

I can not find answer to my concerns.

Since yesterday I am unable to compile my code ionic / cordova in xcode I get an error that I can not understand and solve malgrès my extensive research.

If a person with an idea I'm interested.

Thank you, Aurélien

```
2015-06-10 09:00:29.155 DansMonFrigoApp[10534:1159787] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'ERROR: config.xml does not exist. Please run cordova-ios/bin/cordova_plist_to_config_xml path/to/project.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108844c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c396bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108844aca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010b84498f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   DansMonFrigoApp                     0x0000000108309b0c -[CDVViewController loadSettings] + 428
    5   DansMonFrigoApp                     0x00000001083091eb -[CDVViewController __init] + 1131
    6   DansMonFrigoApp                     0x00000001083092a2 -[CDVViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] + 162
    7   DansMonFrigoApp                     0x0000000108271bb9 -[MainViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] + 121
    8   DansMonFrigoApp                     0x00000001083093fe -[CDVViewController init] + 62
    9   DansMonFrigoApp                     0x0000000108271c6e -[MainViewController init] + 62
    10  DansMonFrigoApp                     0x0000000108271328 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 456
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000108c38788 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 240
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000108c39397 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2540
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000108c3c1de -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000108c3b0d5 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    15  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d0895e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010877841c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010876e165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010876df25 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010876d366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000108c3ab42 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000108c3d900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    22  DansMonFrigoApp                     0x0000000108270fc1 main + 65
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010cbbc145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```